# one line for loop for 2d list wih variable incrementation and 2d list search

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

i am new to the python one liner loops.

i want the user to enter the data into a 2d list while alerting him about the index of data they will enter. 
my code is:

```
flag=0
x=[[int(input("enter the "+ str(flag)+ "number:")) flag+=1 for x in range(0,col)]for y in range(0,row)]
```

the above code shows syntax error. how should i increment the flag value alongside the one line for loop.

the next thing is that i want to search a 2d list for integer value in it

```
x=[[0,3,2],[1,1,1],[9,2,2]]
for i,j in enumerate(x):
    try:
        y=j.index(1)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    print(i,y)
```

the above code works fine for a single item searching but i want the index of every 1 in the list.whereas the above code only returns the index of the first "1" it encounters i.e "1 0"

thank you in advance.

Comment: Take this comment lightly because I haven't spent much time on your question yet. But have you considered getting your code to work without the one-liner first? Expand your code and once that's working trim it into a one-liner if you must.

Comment: @Torxed yea i've done that and it's works just fine but that's the problem i am unable to shrink it. btw thankx for the advice

Comment: Sweet, can you post that code? It's way easier for us to read a expanded code block and we could shrink it down for you based on what you've tried above.

Comment: @Torxed i got the answer but thankx a lot anyways. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that a list comprehension has to yield a value, and you are trying to execute the `flag +=1` inside of it.

It would be clearer if you did it like so:

```
>>> flag = 0
>>> row = 1
>>> col = 3
>>> x=[[int(input("enter the number [{}][{}]:".format(y, x))) for x in range(0,col)] for y in range(0,row)]
enter the number [0][0]:1
enter the number [0][1]:2
enter the number [0][2]:3
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Alternatively, to achieve exactly what you wanted, you can do something like this:

```
>>> y=[[int(input("enter the {} number:".format(x+y*row))) for x in range(0,col)]for y in range(0,row)]
enter the 0 number:1
enter the 1 number:2
enter the 2 number:3
>>> y
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Update for the second part of the question:
You can use more list comprehensions for that:

```
>>> y=[[int(input("enter the {} number:".format(x+y*row))) for x in range(0,col)]for y in range(0,row)]
enter the 0 number:0
enter the 1 number:1
enter the 2 number:1
>>> y
[[0, 1, 1]]
>>> for arr in y:
...   print [index for (index, val) in enumerate(arr) if val == 1]
...
[1, 2]
```

Comment: and for the second part i want to search every "1" present in the list whereas my code only return the index of the first "1" it encounters i.e "1 0"

Comment: I updated to include an example for the second part of your question